# Stretch cloth to a limit then tear

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I was wondering if there is a way to make cloth stretch to an extent and then tear. For example: have cobwebs(cloth) sticking between an object and wall then, the object starts moving so the cobwebs stretch with the object to a limit, and then it tears (if not possible They can just leave contact with the object).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [$addon](https://blendermarket.com/products/clothfx---dynamic-cloth-tearing-plugin)

Comment: Nice thanks but how to stretch it

Comment: It looks to be a tricky (probably try to contact the author)... basically I tried to Hook "Plane_Original" object, but behaviour is weird. Without addon I was partly lucky with [Sewing feature](https://imgur.com/qR8KL7r), but cut is not broken completely -[connections still drag the cloth](https://imgur.com/zz5yqd1) ... now I'm playing with [Tension Map](https://imgur.com/DccM9ig) (procedurally under GeoNodes) that sounds like the right direction, but in Cloth combination it seems like some circular dependency or  what ever ... I will give it a try this afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Procedural Tearing

So I got something (not ideal), but looks like a working concept ... **Tension Map** used as factor for **Split Edges** under Geometry Nodes.

**Tension Map**
I used geometry node group developed by [CGVIRUS studio](https://github.com/cgvirus/blender-geometry-nodes-collection) (here re-colored to better see just stretch part) ... general issue with that (with tension, node group is great) - the most stretched (red) part is the dragged corner, that is not what we want (to just tear the tip of cloth).

[image]

For that I painted another *Weight Map* (stored in *Vertex Group*) with "fragile" part at centre ... so when mixed together with tension map you get something like this (tension at top edge).

Or  you can paint your place of tearing (called *Custom* in my file), just switch to *Weight Paint* mode, don't forget to change it than under geo modifier panel *Tension Map > Weight Paint*.

[image]
[image]

**Tearing**
To make it all works I had to use three planes here ...

- The first keep it as it is to be used as a reference for Tension node group (I will check that later, there has to be easier way to access original vertex position to compare, I did it somewhere already).
- The second plane with Hook, Cloth and GeoNodes>Tension modifiers
- The third plane is used for final result - Surface Deform, GeoNodes>Tearing, Cloth modifier (modifiers used in this order)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Notes:

- there was an addon for Tension Map, it just didn't work for me under 3.4 (I will check if there is not newer version) addon doesn't need to keep original mesh so on one hand cleaner scene, but for future you would have to care about external addon :)
- Even I Weight paint an edge to be split it always split at least face. Those middle faces in place of tear just faults down so I added *Separate Geometry* node that "deletes" this part
- Luckily for us the "delete" quite nicely compensate missing back stretch of teared part of cloth. Since geometry is changing for cloth sim at every frame, blender continue to sim from that point without knowing about stretch anymore here.
- There is quite nice hack of tearing based just on a few modifiers, check [last video tut](https://openvisualfx.com/2017/09/30/stretching-tearing-cloth-in-blender/)
- Or there was a [build of Blender 2.79](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/Qbbbbc/) with Fracture Modifier that had [Cloth Tearing feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asmbt2gQvRs) (still can be downloaded, just for Mac user -like me, I could not find it there).

Comment: Thank you, this helped alot If you find a solution for the middle part keep me posted please

Comment: OK updated ... check also note links.